# convert a FileInfo array into a String array C#

Tags: c#, file-io

I create a FileInfo array like this

```
 try
            {
                DirectoryInfo Dir = new DirectoryInfo(DirPath);
                FileInfo[] FileList = Dir.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);


                foreach (FileInfo FI in FileList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(FI.FullName);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
```

And this array holds all the file names in folder = DirPath

I thought of looping through the FileInfo array and copy it to a String array. Is this ok or is there a much cleaner method ?

Comment: use [Directory.GetFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) if you need file with **full** path

Comment: var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\test\\", "*.*");

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using LINQ:

```
FileList.Select(f => f.FullName).ToArray();
```

Alternatively, using `Directory` you can get filenames directly.

```
string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(DirPath, "*.*", 
                                       SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Comment: hi i do not want to include files in sub directories ? How can i remove sub directory files ?

Comment: @klijo - Why did you use `SearchOption.AllDirectories`? That's what that does. Either use an overload that doesn't use a `SearchOption` enumeration or change it to `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the other way (convert string array into FileInfo's) you can use the following:

```
string[] files;
var fileInfos = files.Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
List<FileInfo> infos = fileInfos.ToList<FileInfo>();
```

Answer (score 1):

the linq is a great soluction, but for the persons who don't want to use linq, i made this function:

```
    static string BlastWriteFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        string blasfile = " ";
        using (StreamReader sr = file.OpenText())
        {
            string s = " ";
            while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                blasfile = blasfile + s + "\n";
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
        return blasfile;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("your path");
List<string> Files = (directory.GetFiles().Where(file => file.LastWriteTime >= date_value)).Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

If you don't want a filter with date, you can simply convert with the below code

```
List<string> logFiles = directory.GetFiles().Select(f => f.Name).ToList();
```

If you need the full path of the file, you can use `FullName` instead of `Name`.