# How to cast property of IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> to List<string>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm running the following code to enumerate all the available folders and subfolders on a network share,

```
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    var dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (var d in dirList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(d.FullName);
    }
```

The code itself works absolutely fine. However, rather than declare the `var dirList`, I'd like to use a `List<string>` variable directly, but it's not clear to me how to do this.

Comment: [ToList](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist).

Comment: This duplicate is about files, but the idea of solution is the same [convert a FileInfo array into a String array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644767/convert-a-fileinfo-array-into-a-string-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will extract the FullName from the sequence returned by EnumerateDirectories

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"path");
List<string> directories = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                  .Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();
```

The Select method will return an IEnumerable and you can easily convert it to a List with the ToList extension.

However you could get the same result avoiding the DirectoryInfo class with the simpler Directory class (still ToList is required to operate on the sequence returned)

```
List<string> directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path,"*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList` is the secret sauce here.  Mark Seeman is the only one who bothered to mention it specifically (in the comment above).

Comment: Correct @RobertHarvey, albeit without it, the compiler will not allow the code to be generated and a clear error is the result.

Comment: Thank you, the reason I'm using the DirectoryInfo class is because I ultimately want to perform a series of operations based on the CreationTime and LastAccessTime of each directory.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Linq for example:

```
var dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(dir => dir.FullName).ToList();
```

Comment: `ToList` technically isn't Linq, it's just an extension method of `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Where is what is considered "Linq" defined? `ToList` is in the `System.Linq` namespace, and other Linq methods are also extension methods of `IEnumerable`. What is the distinction?

Comment: @DStanley: My point is that "Check out Linq" isn't a particularly meaningful distinction here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ahh I see what you mean now. Thanks.