# How to cast DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories to List<DirectoryInfo>

Tags: c#, ienumerable

This question is related to my previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173046/how-to-cast-property-of-ienumerabledirectoryinfo-to-liststring). In this instance, instead of retrieving the full names of the directories, I try to build of a variable of type `List<DirectoryInfo>`.

This code doesn't quite work

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

throws an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

And this version:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories<DirectoryInfo>("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

throws this error:

> The non-generic method 'DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()' cannot be used with type arguments.

Any suggestions or tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Add a `.ToList()` at the end.

Comment: Have you asked the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173046/how-to-cast-property-of-ienumerabledirectoryinfo-to-liststring) today already?

Comment: Yes, I clearly posted without thinking - apologies. Mohammed, your solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `EnumerateDirectories` method returns type of  `IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>` whereas your expected type is `List<DirectoryInfo>` so that you need to cast `IEnumerable` to `List` with adding [`ToList()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolist) as follows:

```
List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories<DirectoryInfo>("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

`EnumerateDirectories()` returns `IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>` rather than `List<DirectoryInfo>`. They are different types.

You **could** just put a `ToList()` at the end:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

But that's the **naive option**. It's often not as good for performance. There's a **reason** `IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo>` was chosen instead. It has some nice advantages in terms of memory use and just-in-time/lazy operation.

So the **better fix** is probably replacing the type name at the beginning of the line with `var`:

```
DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var dirList = dirInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```